# JQuery or canvas layout tool (snap to grid)

Tags: html, jquery-ui, drupal, grid, snap-to-grid

I'm trying to implement some kind of drag and drop snap to grid similar to something like this
http://wordsquared.com/. Was contemplating trying to use JQuery UI and somehow save the position of the items. Seems like snapping to a grid, and saving would be a fairly common scenario. I was contemplating trying to implement this all in Drupal, any suggestions, examples, things I ay not be aware of would be very helpfull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the [Homebox module](http://drupal.org/project/homebox) may be close to what you're looking for.